# android standard icon for menu, what to fill in the field "Icon"?

Tags: android, icons, android-resources

I want to put a menu item on the action bar (just doing a refresh). I already put my icon (the file name ic_menu_refresh.png) in all drawable folders, but can't get it recognized, I always get this error at compile-time. Pls see attached image as well.

`error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'icon' with value 'ic_menu_refresh').`

Already tried without the .png 
Any tip to fix this? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add @drawable/ic_menu_refresh to your menu item.

Answer (score 2):

It should be "`@drawable/ic_menu_refresh`"

You have to specify where you are pulling the image (drawable in this case) from. Also, you don't need to include the image extension, i.e. the *.png* should go.

You can read more about Menus here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml